# Update just a part of the activity layout when edittext field is active

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have an activity with 2 edittext fields. I want the activity's layout to change when the user taps on any of the edittext fields. The activity should revert to its original state when the edittext field is not active. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `setOnFocusChangeListener()` method on `EditText` object and then you can check if that object has the focus or not with the help of the boolean `hasFocus` in the `onFocusChange()`. This listener method can be applied to any view object. Here's the android developers reference page on it [View.OnFocusChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html).

Sample code:

```
editTextField.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(!hasFocus) {
            //do whatever you want when the object doesn't have focus
        }else {
            //do whatever you want when the object has focus
        }
    }
});
```